# BlobServiceClient singleton?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am adding Blob Storage, while I am following this tutorial: https://www.learmoreseekmore.com/2022/11/dotnet7-webapi-azure-blob-storage-file-management-example.html

This piece:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(_ =>
{
    return new BlobServiceClient(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureStorage"));
});
```

if I use the connectingstring from the access Keys it is everytime blazing fast. responds in around 15ms. When I am falling back on the `DefaultAzureCredentials` the response is rather around the 40 seconds. Not very user-friendly ;)

If I follow this article from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication/?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&tabs=command-line

it states;

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<BlobServiceClient>(x => 
    new BlobServiceClient(
        new Uri("https://<account-name>.blob.core.windows.net"),
        new DefaultAzureCredential()));
```

My question is about this singleton use; would this authentication managed by `DefaultAzureCredential` will give me errors some time? (BTW: respons back in 15ms!)
And is there not same overload as the use for `AzureKeyVault`:

it states:

```
builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(
new Uri(builder.Configuration["KeyVaultAddress"]),
new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

I am a bit surprised by the different notations from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use singleton lifetime.
The TokenCredential you give is used by Azure SDKs in their HTTP pipeline, so it will get a new access token when needed through that. It does not matter that the Storage service is singleton.

Answer (score 1):

`DefaultAzureCredential` acquires a token and caches it in the credentials instance. Token lifetime and refreshing is handled automatically, so you don't need to worry about any of that.

It is advisable to [reuse Azure SDK clients](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/lifetime-management-and-thread-safety-guarantees-of-azure-sdk-net-clients/) throughout the application lifetime, so you should register them as singletons.